# Raspberry Pi GPIO and swing timer not working

Tags: java, swing, timer, raspberry-pi, gpio

I am working on a project that keeps track of events occurring periodically. The project will collect data about the event and then report, via e-mail, at the end of the time period about the events that occurred.

I am using a Raspberry Pi 2 board and the event is triggered by a GPIO input. We are using a GPIO handler and a javax.swing.Timer to handle the delay.

```
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioController;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioFactory;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioPinDigitalInput;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.PinPullResistance;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.RaspiPin;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.event.GpioPinDigitalStateChangeEvent;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.event.GpioPinListenerDigital;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.Timer;
import com.myproject.MySettings;

public class main {
    private Timer eventTimer = new Timer(0, null);
    private static int counter = 0;
    private static MySettings = new MySettings();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final GpioController gpio = GpioFactory.getInstance();
        final GpioPinDigitalInput myButton = gpio.provisionDigitalInputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_02, PinPullDownResistance.PULL_DOWN);
        myButton.setShutdownOptions(true);

        eventTimer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent eventArgs) {
                // send e-mail
                counter = 0;
                eventTimer.stop();
            }
        });

        myButton.addListener(new GpioPinListenerDigital() {
            @Override
            public void handleGpioPinDigitalStateChangeEvent(GpioPinDigitalStateChangeEvent eventArgs) {
                if (myButton.isHigh()) {
                    counter++;
                    if (!eventTimer.isRunning()) {
                        MySettings.update();
                        eventTimer.setDelay(MySettings.frequency * 60 * 1000);  // frequency is in minutes. Set delay to milliseconds
                        eventTimer.start();
                    } // else timer is running so do nothing
                }
            }
        });

        while(true) {
            Thread.sleep(300);
        }
    }
};
```

We took the GPIO part out of it with the following test application. The swing timer appears to be working fine on the PI with the following code:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.Timer;


public class tester {
private static Timer eventMonitorTimer = null;// = new Timer(0, null);//
private static long startTime = 0;
private static int count = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("Hello World");

    System.out.println("Creating timer...");
    eventMonitorTimer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
        // do stuff         @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("Delay: " + eventMonitorTimer.getDelay());
            count++;
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
            eventMonitorTimer.setDelay(count * 1000);
        }
    });
    System.out.println("Timer created");
    if (!eventMonitorTimer.isRunning()) {
        System.out.println("Starting timer...");
        eventMonitorTimer.start();
    }
        while(true){
            Thread.sleep(300);
        }
    }
};
```

The above code increased the delay each time and the timer appeared to be working properly. But with the first code sample and the GPIO event handler, it does not appear to work properly. The Timer appears to be triggered immediately when a GPIO event occurs. This not what we desire. Any ideas what is going on here?

Comment: So timer works in general but differently in your GPIO-based Pi code, and I think you are saying that the timer is timing out immediately. What is the actual value of MySettings.frequency used in the first code to set the timer delay? BTW the term "frequency" means e.g. number of things per second, if the value in your "frequency" attribute means some time period in e.g minutes then a less confusing name for the attribute would be maybe "interval" or "period".

Comment: Yeah I agree. We shouldn't use the term frequency :).

The MySettings class is just a place holder. We actually read the value from disk differently. It gets saved through a web UI. The value we were trying to use was 5 (for 5 minutes). Every time the code for the timer actionPerformed would execute as soon as we had a GPIO state change.

On a hunch from another friend, we changed it from a state change event to a trigger event and started to kind of work. I'm not sure why that would make any difference. Thoughts?

Comment: Sorry, no idea.